# Highcharts - accessing overlaying data points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a scatter series with two points that have the same coordinates. Each point has different data associated with it (for example weight and height of different people - two different people can have exactly the same height and weight):

```
series: [ {
            data: [{x:193.5, y:80.7, name:'danny'},
                  {x:193.7, y:90.7, name:'oren'},
                  {x:193.7, y:90.7, name:'josef'},
                  {x:195.5, y:80.3, name:'thomas'}]
        }]
```

Full example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5ncR/1/).

When viewing the tooltips of the chart, the tooltip of the second point shows:

```
Oren: 193.7,90.7
```

Making the data of *josef* inaccessible.

I would like to make the data of both *josef* and *oren* accessible, for example by putting them inside of the same tooltip.

```
Oren: 193.7,90.7
Josef: 193.7,90.7
```

How would you achieve this effect?

**assume a very large data set - iteration over the entire series each time is not an option.**

Comment: You should do a better construct of your data array.....like when 2 people share the same point it should be contructed like this:       series: [ {
                data: [{x:193.5, y:80.7, name:'danny'},
                       {x:193.6, y:90.6, name:'oren and josef shared the same point'},                    
                       {x:195.5, y:80.3, name:'thomas'}]
            }]

Comment: This is a great idea, but there is a quite a lot of separate data on each point. The only shared thing are the coordinates.

I would rather treat them as a single point only as a last resort.

Comment: Then you should do apply a ordenation algorithm on that array first...the  when you have your array in order then construct the new one with the desirable contruct ;)

Comment: That's good too.

I was hoping highcharts would have some kind of proximity map mechanism, so I could just get all points in radius R from coordinates X,Y?

Comment: Other aproach is putting the duplicates in a different data, like this  series: [ {
                data: [{x:193.5, y:80.7, name:'danny'},
                      {x:193.7, y:90.7, name:'oren'},                   
                      {x:195.5, y:80.3, name:'thomas'}]
            },
              {
                data: [
                      {x:193.7, y:90.7, name:'josef'}]
            }    
                    ]

Comment: So you would like to display tooltip for both points or something different?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Tooltip formatter ( http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip ) to manually format your tooltips.

In the formatter compare x and y value of all other points in the series(this.series) If the values are the same, add the name of these points to the tooltip.